# Await an unknown set of blockers before executing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blocking

I have a set of tasks that have subtasks that is executed in order. However, I want the subtasks to execute in sequence, and only start when an unknown set of blockers are cleared. To illustrate the problem, I have the following scenario:

A task, ConsumeIcecream, consists of the subtasks BuyIcecream, OpenIcecream, EatIcecream, in that order. This can be started in the method SpoilYourself, which starts the ConsumeIcecream task.

Another task, LetKidConsumeIcecream has similar subtasks: BuyIcecreamForKid, OpenIcecreamForKid, GiveIcecreamToKid, KidEatsIcecream. These both can be started in the method SpoilYourselfWithKid, starting both tasks in parallell. This has a blocker, though, in that the OpenIcecream subtask cannot be done before the subtask in the other task GiveIcecreamToKid is completed since everyone knows that you cannot indulge yourself before your kids has gotten what they want.

Likewise, if you have several kids, tasks started in the method SpoilYourselfWithMultipleKids, then the task OpenIcecream is blocked by several GiveIvecreamToKid subtasks, or possibly some other subtask as well, e.g. GiveLollipopToKid.

I would like the tasks to be ignorant of everything but which subtasks it controls and the order of it, and the subtasks to be ignorant of everything but a list of "somethings" that some time all should give a "Go on, do what you want". I would like the method to set up the dependencies before starting the tasks, but other than that be ignorant of what the tasks do, so that they can be easily exchanged or altered.

How can this be achieved? I am using C# .net framework 4.6.1. I was thinking of Observer/Observable from Reactive extensions scenario, but that didn't feel right, not even the AsyncSymbol stuff. Anyone got some tips?

Thanks in advance.

/Tryggen

Comment: It's not clear how much generic you want answers to be. This could be architectured in a lot of ways.

For instance, a controller which has the knowledge of prorities on kind of activities wouldn't be enough ?

Comment: I see a ton of text and no code. Rather than wait for people to suggest strategies, I find it's much easier to try something and see where it gets you. As you are writing code, roadblocks in the interface or API mismatches become much more obvious than when you're sitting in a chair, reasoning about how it might look. Start simple: if you have tasks and queues of things to do, just model those explicitly, and write the API as if they existed just as how you would want them to be. Don't implement anything yet, just set up the interfaces. Then see if that seems to match some existing technology.

Comment: And with regards to those technologies, Rx is a big hammer with a big learning curve. Check out the [basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) first.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
I have been trying a "normal" observer-observable pattern instead, where the observer holds a dictionary with id/state to see if it's allowed to start or not. When an update comes, it's with the id and the state, and if that clears the last of the subtask's list, it is good to go. If this can solve my problem I was correct in the observable pattern, but wrong in the RX approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it by using an observable pattern together with a list of tasks and blockers (id and bool). The tasks were started when all blockers were resolved, and were prompted to try to start every time a blocker were resolved.
Thanks for the tips and thoughts.